# Custom Service Endpoint in Azure Devops: clear user and password fields when another field changes

Tags: azure-devops, custom-controls

I´m developing a Custom Service Endpoint in Azure Devops which includes a "config" field (with some configuration stuff) and user and password fields. Could it be possible to clear the user & password fields if someone edits the endpoint and changes the "Config" field?

Idea is to enforce user to retype user/password if config field changes.

Regards.

Comment: You can try to add a jqury [change event](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_change.asp), and then add [empty() method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_empty.asp) to clear the contents of username/password elements. For example`$("input").change(function(){
   $("div").empty();
});`

Comment: Thank you for your answer @HughLin-MSFT. No way of doing this in the vss-extension.json at inputdescriptor level? I´ve seen some interesting params [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-api/inputdescriptor) like "DependencyInputIds" and "HasDynamicValueInformation" but no clue about how to use them

Comment: I am afraid you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this feature is currently unavailable in azure devops. There should be no feature to force the specified field to be cleared based on the change of other fields. Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops) you can refer to.

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) , which is our main forum for product suggestions.After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.